# How to shrink MPMoviePlayer Controller view

Tags: iphone, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using iPhone SDK 3.1.3
I am looking to play file using MPMoviePlayer controller. It is playing in full screen view.

Is there way to scale MPMoviePlayer Controller view to play file in small view in iPhone SDK 3.1.3?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately customizing MPMoviePlayer frame is available only starting SDK 3.2.